# Need to connect a Nikon D3200 to a windows laptop and use it as webcam

Tags: dslr, obs, studio

I need to use a dslr as a webcam on my laptop, windows 11. The dslr that I have is a nikon d3200.

I then want to use the camera on OBS Studio when I am live streaming.

What are the different ways for me to do so?

I tried with digicamcontrol. I connected via the usb port on the camera and the usb on the laptop. But when I used hdmi I couldn't find the camera on my laptop.

Comment: What does your manual recommend? And what do you mean by "connected via USB...hdmi couldn't find the camera"?

Comment: The first way that I tried to connect my nikon d3200 to my laptop was via it's usb cable. This way worked but not how I wanted it to. The solution was to connect the camera to the laptop with an hdmi cable and a video capture card. The hdmi cable has a mini hdmi male at one end and the other end, an hdmi female. The hdmi was connected to the video capture card and the card connected to the laptop ( usb 3.0 port ). The next issue that we have to tackle now is to connect 2 more cameras to the laptop, that is 3 at the same time.